# Container View in Swift

Tags: swift, swipe, uicontainerview

My goal is to have a main view, then swipe right to go to the next view, and again for the 3rd (so 3 different view controllers, all showing different information that is related to the main view), which seems to me like one of the most common features in most apps. Creating segues to other view controllers via buttons or tabs is super easy (just click and drag), but for some reason they make this common feature stupidly complicated for something that should be just as easy as simple segues in the storyboard.

I first started out researching the page view controller, only to find out that's not what I wanted and was too annoying to work with.

I think I found out that Container View is what I need, creating child views and what not. Does anyone know a good step by step tutorial to show you how to set all this up in the storyboard, like, a dummy's guide? I'm a severe novice, so a lot of the docs people point me towards have broken links, outdated code, or might as well be ancient Egyptian hieroglyphics.

Oh, and I'm learning Swift, not objective C!

Comment: _"i'm learning Swift! not objective c!"_ Your learning a bit of Obj-C wether you like it or not. There are tons of Obj-C resources out there, and they are still relevant if yo learn how to translate the syntax. So don't dismiss Obj-C so quickly :)

Comment: @AlexWayne: I see this kind of statement everyday. While your advice is correct, it is important to explicitly emphasize that the O.P. is learning to use _the Objective-C runtime_, and not the language. Though seemingly obvious to you, a novice may not be able to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you need to do anything other than use multiple view controllers to swipe through, passing data from one to the next, and so forth.  I don't think using multiple views (parent / child views) is actually what you're after.

This is a very simple tutorial that will explain how to pass data through segues.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guSYMPaXLaw